# What is the highest coefficient of $(1,\cdots,1)*(e,\cdots,e) \pmod{X^N+1}$?

Tags: group-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

Suppose the polynomials

$$p(x) = (1,\cdots,1) \in \mathbb{Z}^N[X]$$

$$e(x) = (e,\cdots,e) \in \mathbb{Z}^N[X]$$

If we do $p(x)e(x) \pmod{X^N+1}$, then which is the value of the highest coefficient of the result?

**I'm thinking like this:**

$$p(x)e(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{N+N} c_k x^k$$

So the coefficients will be the highest when $k = N+N$ which is the highest, because then we're going to sum the highest amount of elements. But I'm not very condifend on this part because this coefficient gets reduced later. Anyway

$$c_k = \sum_{i=0}^k p_i e_{k-i} = \sum_{i=0}^k 1*e = k*e$$

but on the reduction part I'm totally lost

Comment: What do you mean by $*$?

Comment: @Shaun polynomial multiplication in  the usual sense

Comment: Thank you. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: You switch from $N$ to $n$. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Mike fixed!!..

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs - Did I understand your question correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I've understood your question correctly, so let me first rephrase using notation I'm more familiar with.

> Let $e \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let $p(x)$ be the polynomial $$ p(x) = x^N + x^{N-1} + \ldots + x + 1 .$$
> Consider the polynomial $$ e\cdot p(x) = e x^N + e x^{N-1} + \ldots + e x + e .$$
> (This polynomial is called $e(x)$ in the question, which risks confusion between the polynomial $e(x)$ and the integer $e$. I'll avoid the notation $e(x)$ altogether, and $e$ refers simply to the integer.)
>
> What is the leading coefficient of the product of these polynomials, after reducing modulo $x^N + 1$? In other words, what is the leading coefficient of
> $$ e \cdot p(x)^2 \quad(\text{mod } x^N + 1) ?$$

Now for the answer.
Let's leave out the factor $e$ for now, and just focus on $p(x)^2$.
Note that
$$ p(x)^2 = x^{2N} + 2 x^{2N-1} + 3 x^{2N-2} + \cdots + (N+1) x^N + \cdots + 2x + 1 .$$
In other words, the coefficients of $p(x)^2$ are $(1, 2, 3, \ldots, N, N+1, N, \ldots, 3, 2, 1)$.
We now have to reduce this polynomial mod $x^N+1$. As a warm-up, note that
$$ x^N = -1 \quad(\text{mod } x^N + 1) .$$
This means that we can easily reduce mod $x^N+1$ by replacing factors of $x^N$ by factors of $(-1)$. We get

\begin{array}{lllllllllll}
p(x)^2 &= x^{2N} &+ 2 x^{2N-1} &+ 3 x^{2N-2} &+ \cdots &+ N x^{N+1} &+ (N+1) x^N &+ N x^{N-1} &+ \cdots &+ 2x &+ 1 \\
&= 1 &- 2 x^{N-1} &- 3 x^{N-2} &- \cdots &- N x &- (N+1) &+ N x^{N-1} &+ \cdots &+ 2x &+ 1
\end{array}

(modulo $x^N + 1$). We are interested in the leading term, so we collect all the coefficients for $x^{N-1}$:

$$ p(x)^2 = (N - 2) x^{N-1} + \cdots \quad (\text{mod } x^N+1) .$$

In other words, ignoring the factor of $e$, the answer is $N-2$. If we put the factor of $e$ back in, everything just gets multiplied by $e$ throughout, giving us the final answer

$$ e (N - 2) .$$